# How could the softmax layer be used as one of the middle layers in a neural network and be backpropagated properly?

Tags: python, machine-learning, matrix, pytorch, computer-vision

I am currently making my own machine learning library in c++ as an exercise to help me improve my coding skills and to improve my understanding of machine learning. I am currently making a visual transformer from scratch in order to better my understanding of transformers and how they can be used for images. Part of the code that I am trying to re-create the backward pass for is below:

```py
energy = torch.einsum('bhqd, bhkd -> bhqk', queries, keys) # batch, num_heads, query_len, key_len
            
scaling = self.emb_size ** (1/2)
att = F.softmax(energy, dim=-1) / scaling
```

where queries and keys are 4th dimensional tensors, and the softmax function is applied to each channel, and `energy` is matrix multiplication applied to each individual matrix. To recreate the back propagation I am trying to do it in terms of smaller 2D matrices.

I am going to define `q` as a `3x2` matrix and `k` as a `2x3` matrix. Therefore if I were to multiply them and get a matrix `a` I would get a `3x3` matrix, once the softmax function is applied the dimensions stay the same.

What I am having trouble with is finding the gradient of `q` and `k` with respect to the loss. This is how I would find the gradient of `a` or in this case `dLdA`:

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
  for j in range(len(a)):
       if i == j:
           dLdA[i,j] = a[i] * (1-a[i])
       else: 
           dLdA[i,j] = -a[i] * a[j]
```

I put it in terms of python for easier readability. From there I would get a `9x9` matrix for `dLdA`. From there I need to get `dLdQ` and `dLdK`. Where `dLdQ` = `dLdA`*`dAdQ` and `dLdK` = `dLdA` * `dAdK`. If from there I wanted to compute the Jacobian of `dAdK` from what I understand I would get this:

```py
dAdK = 
[dA1dK1 dA1dK2 ... dA1dK6]
.
.
.
[dA9dK1 dA9dK2 ... dA9dK6]
```

Because there are `9` total elements in `a` and `6` total elements in `k`. Where `dAdK` is then a `9x6` matrix and `dLdA` is a `9x9` matrix when you do matrix multiplication you get a `9x6` matrix, but `k` is a `2x3` matrix. What am I missing to be able to backpropagate this correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am basing all the math to answer this question off [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602822/how-can-the-jacobian-of-the-softmax-function-be-used-for-calculating-the-gradien/4602990#4602990). If you want an in depth explanation of why the math works I recommend reading it. This is how it would be implemented using `numpy` in a simpler way, this is how it would work:

```
class Linear:
    def __init__(self, in_rows, out_rows):
        self.Weight = np.random.rand(out_rows, in_rows)
        self.Bias = np.random.rand(out_rows, 1)
        self.prev = None
        self.LR = 0.01

    def forward(self, x):
        self.prev = x
        a = np.dot(self.Weight, x)
        a += self.Bias
        return a
    def backward(self, dx):
        db = np.sum(dx, axis=len(dx.shape)-1)
        db = db.reshape(self.Bias.shape)
        self.Bias -= (db*self.LR)
        dw = np.dot(dx, self.prev.T)
        dl = np.dot(self.Weight.T, dx)
        self.Weight -= (dw * self.LR)
        return dl

class Softmax:
    def forward(self, x):
        mx = np.max(x, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        x = x - mx  # log-sum-exp trick
        e = np.exp(x)
        probs = e / np.sum(np.exp(x), axis=1, keepdims=True)
        return probs

        
    def jacobian(self, a):
        r = a.shape[0]
        c = a.shape[1]
        output = np.zeros((r,c,r,c))
        for i in range(output.shape[0]):
            for j in range(output.shape[1]):
                for r in range(output.shape[2]):
                    for s in range(output.shape[3]):
                        if(i == r and j == s):
                            output[i][j][r][s] += a[i][j]*(1-a[i][j])
                        else:
                            output[i][j][r][s] -= a[i][j]*a[r][s]
        return output

    def backward(self, dx):
        jac = self.jacobian(dx)
        jac = np.sum(jac, axis=(0,1))
        return jac

def train(x, wanted, m):
    model = [Linear(3,4), Linear(4,4), Softmax(), Linear(4,3)]
    for i in range(0, m):
        curr = x
        for layer in model:
            curr = layer.forward(curr)
        dL = curr - wanted
        if(i % 10 == 0):
            print("current error sum: ", np.sum(dL))
        for layer in reversed(model):
            dL = layer.backward(dL)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.random.rand(3,2)
    wanted = np.random.rand(3,2)
    
    train(x, wanted, 100)
```

One of the outputs I got was the following:

```
current error sum:  9.846307612361286
current error sum:  5.5827143820787395
current error sum:  3.073972734037421
current error sum:  1.622572236217964
current error sum:  0.7876682647260167
current error sum:  0.3118719708795148
current error sum:  0.04493155201662072
```

Which shows that the error is able to be corrected. Obviously a better network can be made, and a better error function can and should be used. This is just a demonstration using computer science to implement the post mentioned above. This is another reason I wrote everything out without as much optimization. One thing to be noted is that I did add that in the backward function, the Jacobian was added over the first 2 dimensions of the 4D tensor to turn it into a 2D tensor. The operations done come out to the same answer if the 4D jacobian of dA/dW and dA/dx were used to find dL/dW and dL/dx respectively and then summed afterwards. This is done to make the program slightly more efficient and easier to show the separate layers and how it would translate to a usual `torch.nn.Linear` layer.